# Batch file to compress subdirectories

Tags: windows, batch-file, compression, 7zip, winrar

I am trying to write a batch script that will run automatically compressing subdirectories using winrar or 7-zip:

Example:

```
 My Pictures
    Pics1 (Pics1.zip)
        File1.jpg
        File2.jpg
        File3.jpg
    Pics2 (Pics2.zip)
        File4.jpg
        File5.jpg
    Pics3 (Pics3.zip)
        File6.jpg
        File7.jpg
    ...
```

How do i write script.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**(1) Using WinRAR:**

`WinRAR` includes two command-line tools, `rar.exe and unrar.exe`, where rar.exe compresses and unrar.exe uncompresses files.

Both are located in the `C:\Program Files\WinRAR` folder in the installable version.

Assuming, if there are multiple subfolders under `C:\MyPictures` and you want each subfolder to get its own .rar file , in the parent folder.

From a batch file, this works for you:

```
@echo off
setlocal
set zip="C:\Program Files\WinRAR\rar.exe" a -r -u -df
dir C:\MyPictures /ad /s /b > C:\MyPictures\folders.txt
for /f %%f in (C:\MyPictures\folders.txt) do if not exist C:\MyPictures\%%~nf.rar %zip% C:\MyPictures \%%~nf.rar %%f
endlocal
exit
```

**Explanation....**

1. It'll create .rar files of all the folders/subfolders under parent
   folder C:\MyPictures in the same parent folder.
2. Then, it'll delete all the original folders/subfolders under parent
   folder C:\MyPictures and thus you'll be left only with the archives
       at the same place.

   - “a” command adds to the archive
   - “-r” switch recurses subfolders
   - “-u” switch. Equivalent to the “u” command when combined with the “a”
     command. Adds new files and updates older versions of the    files
     already in the archive
   - “-df” switch deletes files after they are moved to the archive

If you want to keep the original subfolders, just remove the `-df switch`.

**(2) Using 7-Zip:**

`7-Zip` is a file archiver with a high compression ratio.`7z.exe` is the command line version of 7-Zip. 
7-Zip doesn't uses the system wildcard parser and it doesn't follow the archaic rule by which *.* means any file. 7-Zip treats *.* as matching the name of any file that has an extension. 
To process all files, you must use a * wildcard.

Using 7zip command-line options in a batch file, below works for you:

```
@echo off
setlocal
for /d %%x in (C:\MyPictures\*.*) do "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a -tzip "%%x.zip" "%%x\"
endlocal
exit
```

**Where**

- -a      archive or add
- -t   Type of archive

Answer (score 2):

Here's how to do it in 7-zip.

Let's assume your files are in folder `C:\Pictures\`. Then you can use the following batch command to create multiple archives with the same name as your directories.

```
FOR /D %%i IN (c:\Pictures\*.*) DO "c:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a "%%i.zip" "%%i\"
```

This will compress each folder in the directory `Pictures`. Change `c:\Pictures` to the directory containing your folders. If 7-zip is installed to a different directory, change the `"c:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe"` to a directory where 7-zip is installed.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the great script, I just had 3 issues/changes - directory names with space in name were not working, I just wanted to backup level 1 subdirectories and I wanted to pack all the subdirectories in the current directory (it's great for quick backup of all subdirectories separately). Here is the modification if you need something similar:

```
set zip="C:\Program Files\WinRAR\rar.exe" a -r -u -df
dir /b /o:n /ad > .\folders.txt
for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (.\folders.txt) do if not exist ".\%%~nA.rar" %zip% ".\%%~nA.rar" "%%A"
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach if you need to **recursively** zip files in all subdirs in windows is to use [gitbash](https://git-scm.com/downloads) and the approach described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1005614/how-can-i-recursively-zip-files-in-their-own-folder):

- If you installed git, right click and chose "Git Bash Here"
- Type `find * -type d ! -empty -execdir sh -c 'cd "$1" && 7z a "$1".7z -x!*/ && cd -' sh {} \;`

This will:

- retain folderstructure, place each zip in respective subdir
- recursively zip all files in dirs (excluding empty dirs)
- name zips with directory name

You can also exclude specific types with:

```sh
find * -type d -execdir sh -c 'cd "$1" && 7z a "$1".7z -x!*/ -x!*.7z -x!*.zip && cd -' sh {} \;
```

Answer (score 0):

Non of the provided solutions worked for me.  I have created a script which packs first into *7z* with maximum compression and then create *rar* archive for storage with recovery record (it also deletes the interim 7z archive):

```
@ECHO OFF

SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

FOR /R f:\ZA\SQL2005\ZA\ %%A IN (*.*) DO (
    SET "file_without_suffix=%%~dpnA"

    7z.exe a -t7z -m0=lzma2 -mx=9 -mfb=256 -md=1024m -ms=on "!file_without_suffix!.7z" "%%A"
    REM -ep1 do not store path in archive
    rar.exe a -m0 -rr -ep1 "!file_without_suffix!.rar" "!file_without_suffix!.7z"
    DEL /Q /F "!file_without_suffix!.7z"
    SET "file_without_suffix="
)

SETLOCAL DISABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
```