# Compress subdirectories

Tags: windows, batch-file, compression, rar

I'm trying to compress my subdirectories with structure like this

```
Files1\files11\...(files)
Files1\files12\...(files)
Files2\files21\...(files)
Files2\files22\...(files)
```

I want to compress it to be like

```
Files1\files11.rar
Files1\files12.rar
Files2\files21.rar
Files2\files22.rar
```

without deleting original folders.

I've tried this script

```
for /d %%d in (*\*) do ("C:\Program Files\WinRAR\Rar.exe" a -m5 -s "%%d.rar" "%%d")
```

but it only works for one level.
I also tried [Batch file to compress subdirectories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20779850/batch-file-to-compress-subdirectories) but for some reason it doesn't work. It throws file not found error.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows command line does not support a wildcard for a folder in a file/folder path. `*\*` is therefore invalid.

Two nested **FOR** loops are needed with outer loop running in current directory processing the directories `Files1` and `Files2` and with inner loop processing the directories `files11`, `files12`, `files21`, `files22` and running *Rar* on those subdirectories.

The first batch code creates the archive files

```
Files1\files11.rar
Files1\files12.rar
Files2\files21.rar
Files2\files22.rar
```

with archived directory `files11`, `files12`, `files21`, `files22` included in each archive.

```
@echo off
set "CompressionError=0"

rem Set directory of batch file as working directory.
pushd "%~dp0"

rem For each directory in working directory run a second loop which
rem compresses each subdirectory of current directory to a RAR archive
rem with deleting all files and subdirectories as well as the archived
rem directory itself and name the archive file like the archived directory.

for /D %%D in (*) do (
    for /D %%F in ("%%D\*") do (
        "%ProgramFiles%\WinRAR\Rar.exe" a -cfg- -df -ep1 -idq -m5 -md4m -r -s -y "%%F.rar" "%%F"
        if errorlevel 1 set "CompressionError=1"
    )
)

rem Restore the previous working directory.
popd

rem Halt batch processing if any error occurred on any compression.
if "%CompressionError%" == "1" pause
set "CompressionError="
```

The second batch code creates also the 4 archive files, but with archived directory `files11`, `files12`, `files21`, `files22` not being added to the archive.

```
@echo off
set "CompressionError=0"

rem Set directory of batch file as working directory.
pushd "%~dp0"

rem For each directory in working directory run a second loop which
rem compresses each subdirectory of current directory to a RAR archive
rem with deleting all files and subdirectories as well as the archived
rem directory itself and name the archive file like the archived directory.

for /D %%D in (*) do (
    for /D %%F in ("%%D\*") do (
        "%ProgramFiles%\WinRAR\Rar.exe" a -cfg- -df -ep1 -idq -m5 -md4m -r -s -y "%%F.rar" "%%F\"
        if errorlevel 1 (
            set "CompressionError=1"
        ) else (
            rd "%%F"
        )
    )
)

rem Restore the previous working directory.
popd

rem Halt batch processing if any error occurred on any compression.
if "%CompressionError%" == "1" pause
set "CompressionError="
```

Look in text file `Rar.txt` in program files folder of *WinRAR* for details on used *Rar* switches which is the manual for console version of *WinRAR*.

Both batch files don't show anything during execution and exit automatically  if no error occurs. But batch processing is halted at end if any compression error occurred so that batch user can view the error messages output by *Rar* to console window.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `call /?` explains `%~dp0` (drive and path of argument 0 - the batch file)
- `echo /?`
- `for /?`
- `if /?`
- `pause /?`
- `popd /?`
- `pushd /?`
- `rd /?`
- `rem /?`
- `set /?`

Comment: Thanks. Though there are some things that I still don't understand.
1. Why set CompressionError to empty at the final step of the batch file?

Comment: 2. Are the %%D and %%F mean Directory and Files?

Comment: `set "CompressionError=0"` which could be also just `set "CompressionError="` guarantees that there is no environment variable `CompressionError` with value `1` defined by chance outside of this batch script resulting in halting batch processing at end of this batch script. `%%D` and `%%F` are loop variables for the directories. `%%D` for the directories `Files1` and `Files2` and `%%F` for the subdirectories with relative path to current directory like `Files1\files11`. Adding to outer loop `echo %%D` and to inner loop `echo %%F` makes it possible for you to see the loop variable values.