# How do i ONLY zip the subfolders' content rather than the subfolder itself?

Tags: directory, zip, filenames, subdirectory

I have some folders with content in it like this:

```
Mainfolder
|
|---SubFolder1
    |
    |----ContentFiles1
    |----MoreContentFiles1
|
|---SubFolder2
    |
    |----ContentFiles2
    |----MoreContentFiles2
|
|---SubFolder3
    |
    |----ContentFiles3
    |----MoreContentFiles3
```

---

and would like to zip the contents like this:

```
Subfolder1.zip
 |
 |--ContentFiles1
 |----MoreContentFiles1
 
Subfolder2.zip
 |
 |--ContentFiles1
 |----MoreContentFiles1
 
Subfolder3.zip
 |
 |--ContentFiles1
 |----MoreContentFiles1
```

---

However, theres a problem. There are almost 600 of these folders which need to be zipped. I have tried various methods which almost worked but did just not make the cut, like:

```
 for /d %%X in (*) do "F:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a "%%X.zip" "%%X\" -mx=5 –tzip
```

This bat file gave me almost what i needed, but the format of those zip files were:

```
Subfolder1.zip
 |
 |--Subfolder1(folder)
    |----ContentFiles1
    |----MoreContentFiles1
 
Subfolder2.zip
 |
 |--Subfolder2(folder)
    |----ContentFiles1
    |----MoreContentFiles1
 
Subfolder3.zip
 |
 |--Subfolder3(folder)
    |----ContentFiles1
    |----MoreContentFiles1
```

---

These were sadly unusable.

This didn't seem like too tough of a task at first, but even after researching a little about batch coding and seeing multiple different youtube videos I still don't have a proper solution. The problem is that many of the methods I find either simply don't work or are outdated.

example pics:

[What i get with methods i have tried](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OjCuc.png)

[What i need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qIK5z.png)

Codes which did not even open (either outdated or been used improperly by me):

```
 @echo off
 setlocal
 set zip="C:\Program Files\WinRAR\rar.exe" a -r -u
 dir C:\MyPictures /ad /s /b > C:\MyPictures\folders.txt
 for /f %%f in (C:\MyPictures\folders.txt) do if not exist C:\MyPictures\%%~nf.rar %zip% C:\MyPictures \%%~nf.rar %%f
 endlocal
 exit
```

and:

```
 @echo off
 setlocal
 for /d %%x in (C:\MyPictures\*.*) do "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a -tzip "%%x.zip" "%%x\"
 endlocal
 exit
```

both found from: [Batch file to compress subdirectories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20779850/batch-file-to-compress-subdirectories)

note: i did indeed change the directories of these batch codes, but it did not work, and I am unsure what it meant by the "folder.txt" directories.

---

so if anyone knows anything or could tell me if it's not possible that would be great :).

Comment: Did you try to add an asterisk to your first example `for /d %%X in (*) do "F:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a "%%X.zip" "%%X\*" -mx=5 –tzip` ?

Comment: Hi, well tried it just now, and sadly still the same result, ended up with folders in the zip files. But thanks for the suggestion :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.\folder\*` syntax (dot and asterisk):

```
for /d %%G in (*) do "F:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a "%%G.zip" ".\%%G\*" -mx=5 –tzip
```

Credits to https://superuser.com/a/340062

Comment: omg finally it came out how i needed it, thanks so much :)